# In Black Company, do ambush + sniper shot stack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, campaign-settings, sneak-attack

In the [Black Company](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/48080/black-company) campaign setting, does a scout's ambush damage stack with their sniper shot damage, or does one take precedence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer. Yes, in fact, Ambush damage does stack with Sniper Shot, as it says so at the end of the Sniper Shot description.